# How to get data from external api using GO?

Tags: http, go

I have external data I need to get data from it and this result from an API endpoint

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 30002005,
      "name": "test",
      "info": "{"Version":"7.0.484","CompanyName":"test"}",
    },
    ......
  ]
}
```

I need to get this data and reformat it to my case (put the data into struct then do whatever i need).

The go code:

```
type OldData struct {
    Id            string `json:"id"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
}

func Index() {

    url := "https://exmaple.com/api/posts"
    var bearer = "Bearer XXXXXX"

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", bearer)

    client := &http.Client{}

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    var record OldData

    json.Unmarshal(body, &record)

    fmt.Println(record)
}
```

The result of `fmt.Println(record)` is `{       }`

**Update**

I create thrid for info :

```
type OldData struct {
    Id            string `json:"id"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    Info          string `json:"info"`
}

type Info struct {
    Version     string `json:"Version"`
    CompanyName string `json:"CompanyName"`
}
```

Comment: Check the error return from `json.Unmarshal`. Also, your JSON has an array of records, while you unmarshal into a single record.

Comment: @eMile there is no error with `json.Unmarshal` the code `err = json.Unmarshal(body, &record)

 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 }`

Comment: That's not what you showed in the code. Well, then try this: https://go.dev/blog/json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the JSON there is an array, named `data`. You're trying to unmarshal it to a single struct. Try to define a struct which has a data field which is a slice:

```
type OldData struct {
    Id            string `json:"id"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
}

type OldDataItems struct {
    Data []OldData `json:"data"`
}
```

Now try to unmarshal into an instance of `OldDataItems`.

Comment: Thanks now the get the data, but how can i reach each one of array-like I need to reach to `id` of the data `record.id` does not work

Comment: Since OldDataItems contains a slice named Data, you can reach each element of it using `OldDataItems.Data[0].Id` or you can range over it with `for _, item := range OldDataItems.Data { fmt.Println(item.Id) }`

Comment: Hi sir, pls a little question. I updated the question and in the data, I have a felid called `info` it is string JSON, how can I unmarshal it to a struct. PLS check the update question

Comment: First of all, please don't add newer and newer questions to the original one. This will be misleading someone, who later come here for a solution, since your question now includes my solution too. Open a new question if you want to ask for something else. Now I answer it, but make sure you follow these simple rules next time. Thanks

Comment: You can unmarshal it simply with `json.Unmarshal([]byte(OldData.info), &infoStruct)`